# Extracting only the percent value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a column that includes strings including a percent at the end e.g  **XX: (+2, 30%); (-5, 20%); (+17, 50%)** .
I need to extract the highest % value for each such string and perform this on the whole column.
Any advice will be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Split the string by comma, take the last element and convert it to numeric. Please try it and if you get stuck come back showing an example of input, your code and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, each cell in column `XX` is a cells which contains some percentages. I have included a small test DataFrame I have used:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"XX":["(+2, 30%), (-5, 20%), (+17, 50%)","(+2, 70%), (-5, 20%), (+17, 50%)", ""]})

pattern = re.compile("([0-9\.]+)%")
df["XX"].apply(lambda x: max(pattern.findall(x), default=-1))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0    50
1    70
```

Comment: Thanks. 
This works great with your example, but when I run it on my df it gives me **ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence**. not sure why...

Comment: @RanAntes can you please attach some lines of your table?

Comment: Hi @nikeros. Sorry, I'm a bit new here, still trying to figure out how to post things correctly.  'mosaic_results_short={' (-Y, 25%)',
 ' (-5q, 20%);(+18, 20%)',
 ' (-6q25.3-q27, 11.8Mb, 30%)',
 ' (-1, 25%);(-10q, 20%)',
 ' (+5, 20%)'}' .   This works, but when I use it on my full column I get the error. Maybe due to empty cells that I have there? I also tried to  use 'dropna' and than run it, but getting the same error. Thanks for your patience - as I mentioned, I'm still learning how to post here

Comment: @RanAntes Let me manage that and edit - my concern was that my `DataFrame` test did not reflext your format. I have added a default value in the max computation (-1, but you can use whatever you want). Let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks @nikeros. I'm not sure what you mean. what do you suggest I check? As I mentioned, your expample was good, and worked on this short list I specified in the previous comment. It throws me an error when I apply it to my original data which has more rows.

Comment: @RanAntes I mean - I changed the code to work with empty rows. Try to run the code now on your data

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks so much @nikeros

Answer (score 0):

this code returns the most value in a column having percents

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['2.3%', 1],['5.3%', 3]]
data  = pd.DataFrame(data)
first_column = data.iloc[:, 0]
percent_list = []
for val in first_column:
    percent_list.append(float(val[:-1]))
print(percent_list[np.argmax(percent_list)])
```

Comment: Thanks, @saeed sarbaziazad. My first value is (-Y, 25%), (-5, 20%), (+17, 50%) and as I run the code you suggested I get **ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' (-Y, 25%'**

Comment: oh
its because of your splitter (',') in the string.
you can alter the ',' to '.' in your data or write the following code in first line of for loop:
    val = val.replace(',', '.')